# php profiler for ioncube

Tags: php, profiler, whmcs, ioncube

I have a problem with WHMCS which is encoded using ioncube.
My problem is that the administration is sometimes very slow.
This problem only occurs occasionally. Approximately once an hour and occurs only in the administration.

I need to find out at least what file is causing this.

Is there a profiler that could help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: "IonCube" is vendor-speak for "paid support contract".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.